# Forcing specific SPN for URL in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, kerberos, integrated-security

I'm experiencing inconsistent behaviour when using the .Net framework (C# as well as Powershell) to access a Kerberized HTTP service. It relates to our DNS configuration, and our use of **CNAMEs** instead of A-records for Kerberized services. The workaround suggested by Microsoft is to ensure that you're using A-records for your hostnames, but this is not an option in my corporate environment.

I need a solution that will allow me to force a specific SPN for a specific URL, ensuring that I use the same hostname for the SPN as for the URL. Alternatively, an option to force a consistent policy for resolving URLs to SPNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, once you know what you're looking for, the solution it quite easy to find ;-) In this example, I'm using a HTTPS web service on port 8080:

**C#:**

```
System.Net.AuthenticationManager.CustomTargetNameDictionary
    .Add("https://my-service.tld:8080/", "HTTP/my-service.tld");
```

**Powershell:**

```
[System.Net.AuthenticationManager]::CustomTargetNameDictionary.
    Add("https://my-service.tld:8080/", "HTTP/my-service.tld")
```

Do not forget the trailing slash. Remove `:8080` if using port 80.

References:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.authenticationmanager.customtargetnamedictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Warning: It seems .Net 4.5.1 ignores additions to the CustomTargetNameDictionary. 4.5 seems to work fine.

Comment: I might be seeing this one too - do you know if it affects versions post 4.5.1 or if they have a bug logged for it?